# ADB as post-build event in Visual Studio 2010 makes it freeze

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, adb, post-build-event

I am calling `adb` as post build event in Visual Studio 2010. Sometimes, it makes Visual Studio to stop responding (e.g. when the device is not connected).

However, when I invoke `adb` from command line, it outputs `error: device not found` and returns. Do you experience the same issue? How to fix or avoid it conveniently?